# PHP before head - how to use jquery functions

Tags: jquery, wordpress

To create a new user in wordpress i use a frontend form. When the form gets submitted the php-code is executed before the head section of the page. Now all the javascript code (jQuery and and my functions) get loaded in the head part. When the php-part gets executed none of the functions are there which gives me the error:

> ReferenceError: functionone is not defined

```
<!-- WHEN FORM IS SUBMITTED -->
<?php  
    if(isset($_POST['sent']) && $_POST['sent'] == 'true') {

        $username = $_POST['email'];    
        $salutation = $_POST['salutation']; 
        $email = $_POST['email'];   
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
        $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];   
        $company = $_POST['company'];   
        $status = $_POST['leuchterstatus']; 
        $message = $_POST['message'];   

        // Create a new WordPress user
        $userdata = array(
            'user_login'=> $username,
            'user_email' => $email,
            'last_name' =>  $lastname,
            'first_name'    =>  $firstname,    
            'user_pass'   =>  NULL,
            'role' => 'subscriber'
        );

       if ( username_exists( $email ) ) {
            echo '<script> functionone(); </script>';
            }
        else {
            echo '<script> functiontwo(); </script>';
        }
    }
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move that PHP code down so that its output isn't sent until *after* the `head` section has been sent to the browser, so that the `script` elements you're generating occur **after** the ones that load jQuery, etc. Then the function will exist, and your script element can call it.